# How to copy object properties by reference

Tags: javascript

```js
physicsObjects.forEach(obj => {
  let coor = obj.coordinates;
  let vel = obj.velocity;
  obj.coordinates = addVectors(coor, [0.1, 0.1]);
})
```

This gets the reference.

```js
physicsObjects.forEach(obj => {
  let coor = obj.coordinates;
  let vel = obj.velocity;
  coor = addVectors(coor, [0.1, 0.1]); 
})
```

This only changes the "coor". I tried things like creating a temp obj, and replacing the original obj with temp but it is not a direct way of doing this.

How can I acces an objects property by reference? Other than directly accessing it as in the first example I mean. I needed this only now, doing `object.property.property.property = someValue;` can be painful. Is there a javascript equivalent of:

```js
var *objectProperty = &someobject.someproperty;
```

Comment: Maybe you could to bind the function `addVectors` to the object itself, and use `this.coor` to refer to `coor`, instead of passing it as a parameter.

Comment: If the value of the property is a primitive, you can only refer to values. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get to create a getter, which can return you the value like it was a reference.

Comment: I don't have an serious issue with this, I am just experimenting. Thanks for the tip though. It just felt weird, that you can get an object by reference and you can't get an objects property reference.

Comment: Also, you are _reassigning_  the `coor`  variable here. Maybe instead you want your `addVectors` to _mutate_ the object `coor` passed as parameter.

Comment: Only object types can be referered by reference (in JS arrays and functions are also objects).

Comment: I've just wrote the vector functions and physics object,  I will be improving them. Thanks for teaching me a couple of things I couldn't easily find on google

Comment: @AliMertCakar yes, you can get an object by reference, but you can not get a reference to the variable. Same with properties, you can get a reference to the object that is stored in a property *(as long as it is an object)* but you can't reference the property itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`with`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with) syntax, but this is not recommended since

> Use of the with statement is not recommended, as it may be the source of confusing bugs and compatibility issues.

```js
const foo = {
  data: {
    user: {
      name: 'Alice',
      age: 18
    }
  }
};

with(foo.data.user) {
  name = 'Bob';
  age = 24;
}

console.log(foo);
```

Comment: Thanks. It is deprecated by the way

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a more idiomatic approach in JavaScript would be to make use of `this` and scopes:

```
function addVectors(vector) {  // Use only the *second* argument, like [0.1, 0.1], not 'coor')
    let newCoordinates = /* do same calculations as you did */

    // Instead of *return newCoordinates;* at the end: 
    this.coordinates = newCoordinates;
}


// Approach 1:
// Now "bind" the function inside the object, so that "this" refers to it. 

let objExample = {
   velocity: 42,
   coordinates: [1.2, 3.4],
   add: addVectors,
}

// use it like this (in your foreach for instance):
objExemple.add([0.1, 0.1]);



// Approach 2:
// Use 'call' to bind the 'this' parameter to the object dynamically
// (directly in your foreach without any more changes)
addVectors.call(obj, [0.1, 0.1]);
```

For the example you gave, I would go for approach 2, less code needed.

If you reuse this "addVectors" function at different places, that would make sense  to go for approach 1.